# I know how to reverse a string in ruby without .reverse, but is there a way to only reverse odd indexed characters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know how I can reverse a string in ruby without the reverse method

```rb
def reverse(string)
 
string.each_char.inject(""){|str, char| str.insert(0, char) }

end
```

```rb
puts reverse('hello world')
```

but is there a way I can reverse only the odd indices to look like this.

```rb
output: hlloo wlred
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working off of Les Nightingill's answer I came up with this which handles both odd and even length strings using the `reference_index` variable to point to the end of the string or slightly past it as needed.

```
def funky_reverse(str)
  out = ''
  reference_index = str.length.odd? ? str.length - 1 : str.length
  str.length.times{ |i| out += i.even? ? str[i] : str[reference_index - i] }
  out
end
```

```
> funky_reverse('hello world')
=> "hlloo wlred"
> funky_reverse('hello world!')
=> "h!lloow rlde"
```

This looks like a homework question? :D

Comment: nice! i wouldn't of guessed to set one ternary to a variable and plug that into Les Nightingill's ternary. It's not a homework question. It's actually something I came across on youtube, but it was solved in Java. I wanted to recreate it in ruby, but I was stuck on for loops.

Answer (score 1):

that's an interesting problem, here's what I came up with:

```rb
def funky_reverse(str)
  out = ""
  str.length.times{|i| out+= i.even? ? str[i] : str[-i-1]}
  out
end
```

Comment: hey thanks nightingill! thats the same output i was getting in my console, but i am trying to figure how to catch and reverse only the characters that have odd indices.

Comment: I don't understand... this produces the output you said you were looking for. If it's not the desired output, pls update your question with your desired output

Comment: so i included it there in the last code block. it shows the output im looking for. which is "hlloo wlred". its basically reversing only the odd-indexed characters without the .reverse method and without making a copy.

Comment: reverse(string)
=> hlloo wlred
reverse(string)
=> h!lloow rlde

Comment: yes... my `funky_reverse` method produces "hlloo wlred"... isn't that what you asked for? Seems we're miscommunicating.

Comment: yes excuse my miscommunication. so that worked, try reverse_word('hello world!') i get this in my console => hdlrowworldh instead of => h!lloow rlde

Comment: Yes, it's true. I didn't know exactly what you meant by "reverse only the odd indices". So I just worked from your "expected output".  A different interpretation of "reverse only the odd indices" would have the line ` str.length.times{|i| out+= i.even? ? str[i] : str[-i]}` but that doesn't produce your requested output.

Comment: Thanks Les, you definitely took a different approach that had me thinking. It was super close.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
def odd_reverse(str)
  a = [str, str.reverse]
  str.size.times.map {|i| a[i % 2][i] }.join
end

odd_reverse("hello world")
# => "hlloo wlred"
```

This is pretty simple. For each character index `i` it alternates (`i % 2`) taking the next char from either the string or its reverse (`[s, s.reverse]`).